# How to change footer or <div> for different kinds of users in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, css, user-roles, user-access, footer

I am planning to make a website where non website members should see a different view of the footer.

Is this possible using css only?

Comment: For non members you are making changes in css or in html or in both of footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user is logged in, WordPress adds the class logged-in to the body tag, so you can target CSS differently for logged in users.

```
body > footer {
    background: black;
}

body.logged-in > footer {
    background: red;
}
```

for example.

This is only good for cosmetic changes though. Don't try to use it to hide information from non-logged in users as the content is still in the HTML.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so then by all means accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is decently made, there will be a [class `logged-in` added to the body](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) whenever a user is logged in. You could use this class to differentiate the view for members (if they are logged in) and non-members.

Beware that the html sent to the browser will be identical in both cases. This means users can add/remove the `logged-in` tag in their browser and the css will give the other view. So, this is not a good course if you want to show exlusive information to members. Non-members will be able to see it in the html source.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS only but is not safe if you want to display information for only logged in users. Because they can rename the 'logged-in' class in an inspector.

You can use the function `is_user_logged_in()`and put it in an `if else` statement for showing different footer styles or HTML markup.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/